# Is it possible to increase the prune size and get bitcoind to pull previous blocks?

Tags: pruning, block

for example, currently its:

```
  "size_on_disk": 32084546902,
  "pruned": true,
  "pruneheight": 650668,
  "automatic_pruning": true,
  "prune_target_size": 67108864000,
```

Is there a way to decrease the pruneheight? I need the prune height to be 630000.

I increased prune=64000 from prune=32000 but from what I can tell it will just store more blocks going forward?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bitcoin Core doesn't have such a feature. The prune depth controls how many blocks are kept, and you can change that (`-prune=N` option on the command line or `prune=N` in bitcoin.conf), but once a block is pruned, it is gone. If you want to add blocks back, for now you'll need to resync from scratch.

There is no technical reason for this; it's perfectly feasible to implement a mode where desired old blocks are refetched and inserted into the blocks datadir again, but this simply isn't implemented at this point.